# Proof that if $5\mid2a$, then $5\mid{a}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I am studying some Discrete Mathematics and reached the section on simple direct proofs. I was asked to prove that if $5\mid2a$, then $5\mid{a}$. Can someone please tell me if this proof is viable or nor [image]

Comment: Why does $2|c$?

Comment: There is an important component in the proof that cannot be omitted, and that is that $5$ and $2$ are relative prime. Replace $5$ by $6$ and you see the statement does not work.

Comment: Mohammad.Look up Euclid's lemma.

Comment: No.  It isn't valid.  Why is $\frac c2$ and integer? Why isn't $\frac 52$ an integer.  Perhaps somehow $2|5c$ but $2$ doesn't divide either $5$ or $c$?

Comment: Unnecessarily oblique proof:  Let $2c = 5d$ then $5(c-2d) =5c-10d = 5c-2*5d=5c-4c =c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deduce $\,5(\color{#c00}{c/2}) = a\,\Rightarrow\,5\mid a\,$ we need $\,\color{#c00}{c/2}\,$ an *integer*; 
 it's true by $\,5c=2a$ is even so $c$ is even. This must be *explicitly* mentioned for the proof to be *rigorous*.  As others noted we could instead use Euclid's Lemma, but that's a bit overkill when a simple *parity* argument suffices.

Comment: But isn't a "simple parity" argument just a specialized case of Euclid's lemma when $p = 2$?  Otherwise how do you know if $ab$ is even that one of $a$ or $b$ must be even.

Comment: @fleablood The point is that one can (and often does) introduce parity arithmetic long before deeper properties like Euclid's Lemma. Parity arithmetic only requires knowing how to divide by $2$ (with remainder).

Comment: @BillDubuque I wholeheartedly agree, I already learned parity and it's easy to use but I haven't been introduced to Euclid's Lemma yet.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not correct.  When you write about “the integer $\frac c2$”, you are *assuming* that $\frac c2$ is an integer. How do you know that?

You can use Euclid's lemma: since $5$ is prime and $5\mid2a$, then $5\mid2$ or $5\mid a$. But you know that $5\nmid2$. Therefore, $5\mid a$.

Comment: If I proved that $\frac{c}{2}$ is an integer, would that make my proof valid?

Comment: Yes, but proving that is exactly as easy as proving that $\frac a5$ is an integer, which is what you want to prove.

Answer (score 4):

No.  It isn't valid.  Why is $\frac c2$ and integer? Why isn't $\frac 52$ an integer.  Perhaps somehow $2|5c$ but $2$ doesn't divide either $5$ or $c$?

You will need Euclid's Lemma or something equivalent to it.

Euclid's Lemma states:  If $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ (or both).

If you know Euclid's Lemma this is facile. $5$ is prime so $5|2a$ so either $5|2$ or $5|a$.  And $5\not \mid 2$.

I'm assuming either this is an exercise in recognizing the applications of Euclid's Lemma, or that Euclid's Lemma has not been proven yet.

The standard way to prove Euclid's Lemma is with Bezout's theorem (which in turn is proved by Euclid's Algorithm) but for curiosity sake it might be interesting to be prove it directly.

$5-2*2 = 1$

$5c - 2*2c = c$

Now we know $5|2c$ so there is an integer, $d$, so that $2c = 5d$ so

$5c - 2*5d = c$ and

$5(c-2d) = c$.

..... Don't know about you but I think that's kind of neat.

Comment: Euclid is overkill when a simple partiy argument suffices - see my answer.

Comment: Okay, but although parity is intuitive is it actually proven at a level this basic?  I mean if $ab$ is even why does it follow that either $a$ or $b$ is even? Aren't we going to great lengths to avoid realizing we need to prove Euclids lemma *eventually*.

Comment: Usually parity arithmetic is introduced very early in coursed on elementary number theory and discrete math (as motivation for many things that follow).

Comment: Yeah, but is that justified?  I've never seen a number theory explain why parity arguments are justified without some form of circular reasoning. You can't claim $ab=even$ means either $a$ or $b$ is even without either Euclid's Lemma or the remainder theorem.  And you can't prove the remainder theorem without the Archemedian property which I've seldom seen in the first days of a number theory class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include a proof that $c/2$ is an integer. But you can do this from

$$5c=2a\implies c=2a-4c\implies c/2=a-2c$$

If you like, you can rewrite the entire proof as

$$2a=5c\implies a=5(a-2c)$$

Comment: I'm sorry if this might be a dumb question, but how did $\frac{c}{2}=a-2c$ prove that $\frac{c}{2}$ is an integer?

Comment: @MohamedTlili, because $a$ and $c$ are integers.

Comment: @MohamedTlili It's not a dumb question since the above approach obfuscates the essence of the matter. It is much clearer to use a parity argument - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a valid proof:

First, we'll prove if $a|bc$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a|c$.

If $gcd(a,b)=1$, that means there are integers $x$ and $y$ so that $ax+by=1$.Multiplying both sides by $c$ yields $acx+bcy=c$. Note that $a|acx$ and $a|bcy$ so $a|c$. Plug in $a=5,b=2$ and there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that every integer greater than $1$ is a product of prime numbers. This factorization is unique up to the order of primes.

From $5\vert 2a$ you get $2a=5m$ for some integer $m$. Since $2$ and $5$ are coprime, the representation of $a$ must contain the factor $5$, thus $a$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic doesn't state that every integer is a product of prime numbers. It is only for integers greater than 1.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade What's the problem?

Comment: The problem isn't in your proof for OP's problem. It's merely your definition of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic:)

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is applied in the sentence 'the representation of $a$ must contain the factor $5$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It was just a small nitpick:)

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade Thank you for the edit. You are welcome!